# Inspiron 7559 not shutting down 16.04 Gnome

Tags: boot, nvidia, bumblebee, 16.04, inspiron

So far tried 4.5 kernel that did nothing, nvidia drivers stops me from booting with black screen, bumblebee hangs while installing, enabled preliminary support that did nothing aswell, tried with/out secure boot enabled. I've noticed that the usb from which I'm installing, hangs most of the time while booting and I need to hold the power button down to restart and try again, but on my desktop it boots normally. Any ideas?